# how to deal with illumination change

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to detect green citrus fruits in natural canopies using color images.

For below image,

[image]

When applying the following process, I get the below result.

```
image_gray = rgb2gray(image);

strel_erode = strel('disk', 10);
image_erode = imerode(image_gray, strel_erode);
figure, imshow(image_erode);

grayimage = image_erode;
for i = 1:768
    for j = 1:1024
        if(grayimage(i,j) > 100)
            grayimage(i,j) = 255;
        else
            grayimage(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
figure, imshow(grayimage);
```

[image]

This result cannot be good for now because I am newbie on image processing. According to me, I need to deal with illumination change on this image.
If I am not on the right track, please guide and help me.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is? What output were you expecting, why is it not good, and what prevents you taking the next step? I *probably* would not go straight to pixel thresholding, but it doesn't break things for you, and I expect a trained classifier would find the fruit in the second image - just maybe it is not the best starting point, but it should still work.

Comment: I want to split fruit from other parts of image. Fruit will be white and background will be black for best result. According to result, shadow on fruit prevents to detect full circle as it appears. For now, I have no road map, I am using trial-and-error method such as Gabor filter, Hough transform, imerode function in matlab etc. However, for all methods I need to prevent shadows as above image.

Comment: OK, I can understand what you are trying to do. However, you still have no real question. Stack Overflow cannot write you a tutorial or roadmap for image segmentation, at least not anything as good as existing starter material like http://uk.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html

Comment: Thanks for material, but I couldn't completely explain what I want to ask. I'm really wondering how can get rid of the shadow on fruit. How can I eliminate illumination change on image?

Comment: It's a very hard task. You cannot really "eliminate illumination change", but you may be able to ignore it to a degree and better segment the target by using a combination of techniques, and some knowledge of how the fruit appear in typical images. For instance, a texture match might do well due to difference in texture of the fruit from other objects in the image: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/texture-segmentation-using-texture-filters.html

Comment: You are right Neil. Texture differences between fruit and other objects may be helpful to detect fruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few tips: matlab is very slow at loops. If we want fast processing we use "vectorized" forms of equations. So we can replace all this code

```
for i = 1:768
    for j = 1:1024
        if(grayimage(i,j) > 100)
            grayimage(i,j) = 255;
        else
            grayimage(i,j) = 0;
        end
     end
end
```

with this

```
bw_image = (grayimage > 100);
```

what this does is create a binary image. IF the value is > 100 it is true=1; it its <=100 its false=0. This is much faster, easier to read, and it will work no matter what the image size is.

Instead of using illumination, you can convert the image to [HSV colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) if you aren't familiar with it, it converts the RGB values to Hue (color), Saturation(how vivid the color is), ~brightness(the illumination level). The nice thing about this is that you can look for the same color in all lighting conditions, this is exactly what you want. Take a look yourself, in matlab do

```
hsv_image = rgb2hsv(image);
imtool(hsv_image);
```

this will open a window that will let you inspect pixel values. The colors will be strange, this is because matlab expects the image to be RGB values not HSV. so It still plots it, but with weird colors. That's ok, in the bottom left part of the window it says "Pixel info (x,y) [H S V]"

[image]

if you look at different pixels in the fruit you will see they all have similar Hue values ~.22 even in the shadows!! you'll notice that the V value in the shadows is low, but in other places it is high. Using HSV your new mask might be something like this

```
bw_image = (hsv_image(:,:,1) >=.2 & hsv_image(:,:,1) <=.23);
```

if your image is m,n pixels (in your case 768,1024) the HSV color image is m,n,3 matrix. Where the 3 means one layer 1 is Hue, 2 is Saturation, 3 is Illumination. In the notation `hsv_image(:,:,1)` the colon **:** means **all** so it says take all rows, all columns, of layer 1 (the hue).

One problem now, is that this will detect all green in the image, even those leaves in the background. But the HSV colorspace is still very helpful when we want to ignore illumination changes

Using the HSV color space and the segmentation article someone else posted will help you get started

**EDIT**

a little code to show you what the hue values are for your image

```
hsv_im=rgb2hsv(im);      %converts image to HSV
imshow(hsv_im(:,:,1));   %displays only the hue channel/layer
colormap(hsv)            %uses the hue colormap
colorbar                 %displays the colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: Your response is helpful for beginning. However, determined threshold(0.20 to 0.23) is meaningful for only above image. It should be generalized for image set. How to compute threshold specifically for each image.

Comment: well you couldn't really find a generalized threshold for each image of this type. It would have to be done individually, using imtool to find values. There are more advanced methods, but since your background is the same as the foreground(fruit)  you need to be very clever. As I said hue alone won't be enough to find your fruit, but it is lighting invariant so it will help. One method would be to collect lots of images and "train" your classifier, this just means you find the average hue of lots of images. and then use that value for all future data.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have already tried the hough circle transfrom. My guess is that this would - at least in the thresholded image shown by you - would work reasonably well, *although* the left part of the fruit is obfuscated by a shadow. Have you tried providing a reasonable estimate of the circle radius range and - especially - to vary the sensitivity, probably best starting at a very low value for [imfindcircles](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html)?

Comment: I have tried to use houghcircle function at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4985-circle-detection-via-standard-hough-transform/content/houghcircle.m, but I didn't get meaningful result. Is imfindcircles similar to houghcircle function?  What parameters should I pass to houghcircle function for above image?

Comment: They are similar, but imfindcircles offers a more fine grained control over the detection process. Also note that for the implementation you mentioned, you have to provide an image that only contains geometry edges, which you could for example get by applying [link]{http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html} on your thresholded image. I didn't try it, but if I were to use your function, I would start out with the lowest possible threshold (4) and a measurement of the fruits radius in the image (in pixels).